# Determine an entity field type using the criteria API without a warning being displayed in intelij / compiler

Tags: java, jpa

Given the following code, I am attempting to determine if a particular field in the entity model is a `java.util.Date` whilst building a query using `CriteriaBuilder`.
I have managed to determine that the field is in fact a date, but the IDE is producing a warning. I can ignore the warning, but:

> What is the correct way to safely determine the type of the entity field without a warning?

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<ExclFlagViewBE> cq = builder.createQuery(ExclFlagViewBE.class);
Root<ExclFlagViewBE> entity = cq.from(ExclFlagViewBE.class);

Expression<String> field = entity.get(key);
Class<? extends String> type = field.getJavaType();
if (Objects.equals(type, Date.class)) {
    // EVALUATES TO TRUE HERE WHEN THE FIELD IS A java.util.Date
}
```

However, I am getting a warning in IntelliJ:

```
equals() between objects of inconvertible types
Class<capture of ? extends String> and Class<Date>
```

`type.equals(Date.class)` also evaluates to true when the field is a date, but produces the same warning (obviously)

Comment: Why do you use explicit type "String" and particularly "? extends String" if the type could be any type including Date?

Comment: Class<? extends String> doesn't look right.  String is a final class so it can't be extended, there would be nothing other than String itself that matches that.  Class<String> is what you have, which I think is not what you want.  Class<?> would probably make more sense but I suspect there is something else odd here.  The class types are unique you can do if (field.getJavaType() == Date.class)

Comment: In addition to the comment from AlexC, i.e. `Class<?> type = ...`, do `Expression<?> field = entity.get(key)` and you should be OK.

Comment: AlexC: it seems that you are correct, I think the intelij decompiler was issuing me red herrings with the `? extends String>` do you want to post that as the answer it's meant to be `Class<?>`